# Apps Script - Storing the Refresh Token instead of Project Properties

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api, google-sheets

I have a Youtube Analyitics spreadsheet modified from this episode of Script IT!

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVhsK5jH6u8

Is there a way to store the refresh token instead of access token so that the spreadsheet can have persistent access?  I got the refresh token from the OAuth Playground but merely replacing the access token with the refresh token does not seem to work.
Many people use this spreadsheet and I would like to avoid the every hour authentication if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this code sample here - https://github.com/entaq/GoogleAppsScript/blob/master/IO2013/YouTubeAnalytics/oauth2.gs

I've improved the OAuth library there to auto refresh token when it expires. This way its very scalable and you don't have to "bootstrap" and store anything.

Important bits -

```
function attemptTokenRefresh_() {
  var refreshToken = UserProperties.getProperty(refreshTokenPropertyName);
  if (!refreshToken) {
    Logger.log('No refresh token available to refresh with ' + tokenKey);
    return false;
  }
  var requestData = {
    method: 'post',
    payload: {
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
      refresh_token: refreshToken,
      grant_type: 'refresh_token'
    }
  };
  Logger.log('Attempting token refresh');
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(TOKEN_URL, requestData).getContentText();
  storeOAuthValues_(response);
  return true;
}

function storeOAuthValues_(response){
  var tokenResponse = JSON.parse(response);

  var accessToken = tokenResponse.access_token;
  // expires_in is in seconds and Date.now is ms
  var endMs = Date.now() + tokenResponse.expires_in * 1000;
  var refreshToken = tokenResponse.refresh_token;


  //store the token for later retrival
  UserProperties.setProperty(oauthTokenPropertyName, accessToken);
  if (refreshToken) { //on a refresh call we wont get a new refresh token, lets not wipe prev one out
    UserProperties.setProperty(refreshTokenPropertyName, refreshToken);
  }
  UserProperties.setProperty(oauthTokenExpiresPropertyName, endMs);
}
```

Comment: Arun, thank you for the help on this.  I do not seem to be getting a refresh token from my request.  I am under the /youtubepartner scope and I can get one on the OAuth Playground.  I am only getting an access token and expiration.  When I log response I do not see a refresh token there either.

Comment: Make sure to include `&access_type=offline` when you ask for auth for your scopes.

Comment: This is what I have:
    `&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner&response_type=code&access_type=offline`

Does this look correct?  This is not producing a refresh token.

Comment: Have you looked the code link I posted to github? What is your entire URL? If you call https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth with `access_type=offline`, you should get back a refresh_token.

Comment: I am running this function for authorization `function getURLForAuthorization(){
  return AUTHORIZE_URL + '?client_id='+CLIENT_ID+'&redirect_uri='+REDIRECT_URL +
    '&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner&response_type=code&access_type=offline'; //added access type from above api guide 
}`

Please let me know if I'm missing anything.